# Unable to connect to SQL Server using ipaddress or localhost and portno 1433

Tags: sql-server-2019

I have installed Microsoft SQL Server 2019, I am able to connect using hostname and Windows authentication from SSMS, but when it try to connect to it using `localhost` or the IP address and port 1433 from SSMS or DBeaver, it doesn't connect.

I have verified the service status, port no, server logs, all looks good but still unable to connect. Can somebody please help?

Comment: What specifically does *unable to connect* mean? Do you get an error message? If so, what is the exact content of that message?

Comment: Apologies , I missed to attach screenshot with error

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved after enabling server authentication.steps :-
1. In SSMS right click on conection
2. Go to properties-> security
3. Change authentication mode to windows and SQL server from windows authentication.

After making this change , I am able to  connect to the sever using ipaddress.